# How do I populate tables in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

Every example I can find either goes through creating a table without a gui or explains how to populate from a database.  I must be missing something simple but here's what I have so far based off of different tutorials and at [How to Use Tables: Creating a Table Model](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data).

```
private void btnAddRecordToTableActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    String strPledgeArray[][] = 
    {
        {"1","2","3","4","5"}
    };
String columnNames[] = {"Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3","Column 4","Column 5"};
    JTable tblDataGridResults = new JTable(strPledgeArray, columnNames);
}
```

After pressing the button nothing happens however.  What am I doing wrong?

From my reading I think it's because there's no model but every time I see anything about models they are in different classes or using constructors that just create errors in my program.

Comment: From my understanding (which is obviously wrong since its not working) this is all the code you need.

Comment: Learn Java basics before using Swing. And learn to use swing without the wysiwyg Netbeans support first. Programming is not about dragging and dropping components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) code line

```
JTable tblDataGridResults = new JTable(strPledgeArray, columnNames);
```

create a new JTable that isn't added to the GUI

2)  better would be to add ColumnNames and Rows to the DefaultTableModel, please read in the tutorial [how TableModel works](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data)

EDIT

still don't understand ???

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class RemoveAddRows extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Object[] columnNames = {"Type", "Company", "Shares", "Price"};
    private Object[][] data = {
        {"Buy", "IBM", new Integer(1000), new Double(80.50)},
        {"Sell", "MicroSoft", new Integer(2000), new Double(6.25)},
        {"Sell", "Apple", new Integer(3000), new Double(7.35)},
        {"Buy", "Nortel", new Integer(4000), new Double(20.00)}
    };
    private JTable table;
    private DefaultTableModel model;

    public RemoveAddRows() {

        model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
                return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
            }
        };
        table = new JTable(model) {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {
                Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
                int firstRow = 0;
                int lastRow = table.getRowCount() - 1;
                int width = 0;
                if (row == lastRow) {
                    ((JComponent) c).setBackground(Color.red);
                } else if (row == firstRow) {
                    ((JComponent) c).setBackground(Color.blue);
                } else {
                    ((JComponent) c).setBackground(table.getBackground());
                }
                /*if (!isRowSelected(row)) {
                String type = (String) getModel().getValueAt(row, 0);
                c.setBackground("Buy".equals(type) ? Color.GREEN : Color.YELLOW);
                }
                if (isRowSelected(row) && isColumnSelected(column)) {
                ((JComponent) c).setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.red));
                }*/
                return c;
            }
        };
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        add(scrollPane);
        JButton button1 = new JButton("Remove all rows");
        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                if (model.getRowCount() > 0) {
                    for (int i = model.getRowCount() - 1; i > -1; i--) {
                        model.removeRow(i);
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("model.getRowCount() --->" + model.getRowCount());
            }
        });
        JButton button2 = new JButton("Add new rows");
        button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                Object[] data0 = {"Buy", "IBM", new Integer(1000), new Double(80.50)};
                model.addRow(data0);
                Object[] data1 = {"Sell", "MicroSoft", new Integer(2000), new Double(6.25)};
                model.addRow(data1);
                Object[] data2 = {"Sell", "Apple", new Integer(3000), new Double(7.35)};
                model.addRow(data2);
                Object[] data3 = {"Buy", "Nortel", new Integer(4000), new Double(20.00)};
                model.addRow(data3);
                System.out.println("model.getRowCount() --->" + model.getRowCount());
            }
        });
        JPanel southPanel = new JPanel();
        southPanel.add(button1);
        southPanel.add(button2);
        add(southPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RemoveAddRows frame = new RemoveAddRows();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the same page as I linked above.  I don't understand it and when I go through I consistently get errors.  I have to use the GUI provided for me.  Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Use Object[][] array instead of String[][]

JTree constructor takes in 2-Dimension object array as the content of the table, and 1-Dimension string array... and then creates a table.

For eg :

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout

import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

import javax.swing.JTable;

public class Test6 extends JFrame {

    public Test6(){

        this.setSize(300,300);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Mpanel m = new Mpanel();
        this.add(m,BorderLayout.CENTER);

    }


    class Mpanel extends JPanel {


        JTable mTable;


        private Object[][] cells = {{"Vivek",10.00},{"Vishal",20.00}};

                    private String[] columnNames = { "Planet", "Radius" };
        JScrollPane mScroll;

        public Mpanel(){

            this.setSize(150,150);
            this.setComponent();
        }

        public void setComponent(){


            mTable = new JTable(cells,columnNames);
            mTable.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
            mScroll = new JScrollPane(mTable);

            this.add(mScroll);


        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        new Test6().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great but it creates a new one outside of the GUI.  All the examples I can find are similar to this which seems to echo the statement above that this is the more correct way of going about it.  Unfortunately I have to use the table in the gui.  I'm used to VB.NET and it is so much simpler than this.

Comment: Well then add this JTable code to the JPanel or JComponent inside the gui, it will work fine.... this code is just an abstract from my project, in reality it is added to the JPanel, and JPanel is further added to my JFrame